# Using boto3 to check if you can reach one ec2 instance from another ec2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

Let's say you have an instance A and instance B either in the same account or different accounts. I am making a script I was wondering how I can you use boto3 and guarantee that both instances can communicate through a given port or protocol. I am thinking may be I have to first check SGs/NACLs for each instance in the script.

Comment: Perhaps you can just ping or curl instance B from instance A?

Comment: I know but I just want to make a script where its run locally

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using the AWS Reachability Analyzer tool. Here's an example to automate the process with boto3 - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/automating-connectivity-assessments-with-vpc-reachability-analyzer/